# Headphone cushions

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[image]

Trying to make headphones. How would I get a realistic cushioned effect on the headphone cushions? There are tutorials on Youtube for round headphones that use a sewing effect but it doesn't seem to work on these headphones due to the hexagonal shape.

Comment: I would suggest to start by figuring out what you want to model. Why wouldn't you post an image of what you are trying to model? If you don't know, what you want to model, you certainly cannot model it especially if you are still learning modelling. [Choose what you want first](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=headphone+cushions).

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbRKoSC-Z78&ab_channel=Xmaiter3D